# Changes in Cloud-Init Ubuntu

Tags: server, kvm-virtualization, cloud-init

I have been using cloud-init successfully before Ubuntu 19.10 but with the same `user-data`, `meta-data` and `network-config`, 19.10 does not appear to pickup the `hostname` and user configurations and I am unable to login. I went back to try with 18.04 and while that was successful, it seems the naming convention for the interfaces was changed so the `network-config` fails to apply. Previously, I believe it used `ens3`, `ens4` and so forth, but the latest image for 18.04 appears to use `enp1s0`. Is there any way to find the changes that have been implemented for the cloud images? I have looked at [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/+changelog) but I wasn't able to find anything that would indicate these changes.

This is my user-data:

```
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: user
    gecos: user
    sudo: ['ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL']
    shell: /bin/bash
    groups: sudo
    lock_passwd: false
    passwd: ***password***
    ssh-authorized-keys:
      - ssh-rsa 
      - ssh-rsa 
manage_etc_hosts: localhost
package_upgrade: true
power_state:
  delay: "+1"
  mode: reboot
  message: Bye Bye
  timeout: 1 
  condition: True
timezone: Canada/Eastern
```

Comment: Regarding the networking `ens4` etc, these are created based on the make/manufacturer of the network card. As far as I know this has not changed in quite some years. Any convention changes has to do with underlying vm/network card changes

Comment: The only change was from ovs to linux bridges. The virt-install command is the same otherwise, this should be transparent to the vm right?

Comment: you can use udev to force network interface names to be what you want (`eth0`, `wlan0`, etc)